# Add Data Dynamically to Sencha Touch Accordion List (Expandable List)

Tags: sencha-touch

I am using the Accordion Layout for Sencha Touch 2.1.1 from Mitchell Simoens git link : https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.layout.AccordionLayout

I Want To Add data to this Accordian List dynamically at run time

Answer (score 1):

This is just a layout. So, if you want to add data in child panels of the parent panel, give all the panel a specific property say name and then retrieve each panel like this:

```
parentPanel.down('panel[name="first_accordion_item"].setData(myData);
```

That is, just get hold of the child panels/items.